# Parse pushes go to wrong app

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin

I duplicated a previous project of mine in Android Studio to make a similar but different app. First I changed the package name by refactoring the first folder under the "Java" tab, which is my package name. Next, I made sure that I followed the Parse guide to setting up push notifications, where you paste certain code but replace certain instances with your own package name. Parse also requires that you have code like `Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxx")` in the `onCreate` of your application. I also changed this to my new parse app.

However, when I send a push on my old app (the project I copied to make the new app), my new app receives this push even though I changed the project name and the code Parse requires to do push notifications.

I have no idea why this android app is receiving push notifications from the old app and am looking for a way I can stop this. If it matters, the new app is also receiving the pushes from the new parse app, so there are two parse apps that, when I send a push, will trigger a notification in this new app.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing between my dev and release branch of my parse.com database. My suspicion is that valid installation objects are present for the same device in both apps, and since Parse Push uses GCM, the Google servers cannot distinguish between app's coming from either apps, meaning that the device will receive notifications coming from both parse app's.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest possibly?

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

and also in the receiver

```
<category android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.HERE" />
```